# trimming words in a list of strings

Tags: python

I'm writing some code that trims down a words in a list of string. if the last character of a word in the string is 't' or 's' it is removed and if the first character is 'x' it is removed.

```
words = ['bees', 'xerez']
```

should return:

```
['bee', 'erez']
```

So far my solution is:

```
trim_last = [x[:-1] for x in words if x[-1] == 's' or 't']
```

I think this trims the last characters fine. I then to trim the first characters if they are 'x' with this line:

```
trim_first = [x[1:] for x in trim_last if x[0] == 'x']
```

but this just returns an empty list, can i some how incorporate this into one working line?

Comment: First of all `if x[-1] == 's' or 't'` is not doint what you want it to do.

Comment: Just add `else` statement in your list comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

`[v.lstrip('x').rstrip('ts') for v in words]`

Comment: Forgot about those, nice.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing a filter, not a mapping.
The right way would be

```
trim_first = [x[1:] if x.startswith('x')  else x for x in trim_last]
```

Also, your solution should not return an empty list since the filter would match on the second element

Comment: I'd use `x.startswith` instead of string slicing :)

Comment: @Coal_  Why? Is it faster?

Comment: It's less error prone, more pythonic and easier to scale up.

Comment: @Coal_ more readable is a better argument I think. More Pythonic seems to be a bit opinion based in recent years. Regarding scalability, slicing can be expanded to both other objects and longer prefixes. But I guess this is a taste issue and I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

In one step with [**`re.sub()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

```
import re

words = ['bees', 'xerez']
result = [re.sub(r'^x|[ts]$', '', w) for w in words]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['bee', 'erez']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to chime in - since this is in fact, a mapping:

```
map(lambda x: x[1:] if x[0] == 'x'  else x, words)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a one-liner you can use some arithmetic to play with the list slicing:

```
words = ['bees', 'xerez', 'xeret']
[w[w[0] == 'x' : len(w) - int(w[-1] in 'st')] for w in words]
# output: ['bee', 'erez', 'ere']
```

Comment: Not sure if the reduction to a one-liner is worth the loss of readability, but this is a neat trick.

Comment: @asongtoruin I know, there are other more readable solutions, but OP explicitly wanted "one working line", so there you have it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
trim_last = [x.lstrip('x').rstrip('t').rstrip('s') for x in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using two list comprehension for that you can do with one list comprehension :

> one line solution:

```
words = ['bees', 'xerez','hellot','xnewt']

print([item[:-1] if item.endswith('t') or item.endswith('s') else item for item in [item[1:] if item.startswith('x') else item for item in words]])
```

output:

```
['bee', 'erez', 'hello', 'new']
```

> Explanation of above list comprehension :

```
final=[]
for item in words:
    sub_list=[]
    if item.endswith('t') or item.endswith('s'):
        sub_list.append(item[:-1])
    else:
        sub_list.append(item)
    for item in sub_list:
        if item.startswith('x'):
            final.append(item[1:])
        else:
            final.append(item)

print(final)
```